# Which Android Development blogs you follow

Tags: android, blogs

which are the top Android development blogs that you follow.

Please do not mention forums or general android products blogs

Comment: You could also find a lot of useful information about libraries here: http://android-arsenal.com

Comment: [Future Studio](https://futurestud.io/blog/tag/android) for all kinds of Android tutorials, like Retrofit, Picasso, Glide & Gson.

Answer (score 17):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/  obviously,

and Tim Bray's blog: http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/

and Romain Guy's blog: http://www.curious-creature.org/category/android/

Both of them are employees working on Android.

Answer (score 9):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 3):

By blogs I am going to assume websites too which could be useful to imparting knowledge on android and other related fields. Mine would be

[androidworkz](http://androidworkz.com), 
[bogotobogo](http://bogotobogo.com),
[androidguys](http://www.androidguys.com/),
[androidandme](http://androidandme.com/),
[androinica](http://androinica.com),
[phandroid](http://phandroid.com/) and
[talkandroid](http://www.talkandroid.com/).
This sums up about the best android related websites and blogs in my opinion, this list also includes the sites mention above. Have fun reading them... :)

Comment: http://jon.oberheide.org/ this is a very interesting blog too. He is the guy who discovered the first major hole in android securities and would be an interesting person to follow. I am sure he has more to offer.. :)

Answer (score 2):

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/search/label/Android

http://www.curious-creature.org/

and of course the one mentioned below...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the ones already listed, I follow:

- http://www.helloandroid.com/
- http://davanum.wordpress.com/
- http://commonsware.com/blog/
- http://www.amazonappstoredev.com/

Commonsware blog is by far my favorite, and I am sure everyone has seen his helpful posts here on SO.